# Python StringIO.write doesn't like integer zero?

Tags: python, stream, stringio

Why can stream.write output pretty much anything other than zero?

```
from StringIO import StringIO
v0 = 0
v1 = 1
a = [1, 0, v1, v0, "string", 0.0, 2.0]
stream = StringIO()
for v in a:
    stream.write(v)
    stream.write('\n')
print stream.getvalue()
```

With Python 2.7.6, running this code produces:

```
1

1

string

2.0
```

Comment: It turns out that `.write(0)` means `don't write` in `StringIO`'s context. My guess is, in its internal implementation, it probably checks the input first like `if 0:` which always equals to `False`. Is there any reason you didn't convert items to `string` first using `str()`?

Comment: By the way, I would prefer using `cStringIO` over `StringIO`. It is way faster.

Comment: As a matter of interest, Python 3 `io` module (which replaces the StringIO module) produces a TypeError on `stream.write(v)` when `v` is not a string.

Comment: so as `cStringIO.StringIO` in Python 2.7.

Comment: @ozgur Actually I did end up wrapping numbers with str(), but was curious why this should be necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The interface for [`fileobj.write()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.write) requires that you write a **string**, always:

> `file.write(str)`
>   Write **a string** to the file.

Emphasis mine.

It is an implementation detail that for `StringIO()` non-strings just *happen* to work. The code [optimises the 'empty string' case](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/a4a3a8b3f37f/Lib/StringIO.py#l214) by using:

```
if not s: return
```

to avoid doing unnecessary string concatenation. This means that if you pass in any *falsey* value, such as numeric 0 or `None` or an empty container, writing doesn't take place.

Convert your objects to a string before writing:

```
for v in a:
    stream.write(str(v))
    stream.write('\n')
```

If you used the C-optimised version here you'd have had an error:

```
>>> from cStringIO import StringIO
>>> f = StringIO()
>>> f.write(0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: must be string or buffer, not int
```

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but the "write a string" is ambiguous - it could be interpreted as "file.write will output a string to the file", rather than "you must provide a string as input".

Comment: @PeterKrnjevic: the signature of the method is `file.write(str)`. No other file(like) object accepts other types.

Comment: So it would seem. I tried with regular file.write() and it explodes as expected. However, I'm a bit surprised a dynamic language like Python that wouldn't "stringify" types when necessary.

Comment: @PeterKrnjevic: use `print >> fobj, value` or with the Python 3 syntax (after `from __future__ import print_function`) `print(value, file=fobj)` if you want stringification.

Comment: @PeterKrnjevic: that `StringIO.write()` accepts other types at all is really a mis-feature that should have been removed long ago. The new Python 3 I/O infrastructure (available as the `io` module in Python 2) has in-memory file objects that correct the mistake.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like it's at StringIO.py, line 214 (function `write`):

```
if not s: return
```

(`s` being what you are passing to `write`).

In other words, 'falsy' values (such as None, [], 0, etc) will be discarded.

Comment: Including an empty string (which is probably why it is there)

Comment: @cdarke, why do you think they couldn't just pass on the empty string?

Comment: @PeterKrnjevic I'm not certain, but I'm guessing that it is to avoid an unnecessary object creation, so for efficiency.